# Dell Inspiron 6400 Lubuntu

Tags: dvd

Hi I am running the latest release of Lubuntu on a Dell Inspiron 6400 Centrino Duo and 2GB ram

I am have trouble with playing DVD's The video is being pixelated and the sound is choppy. It sounds like the DVD is being read a lot.

I have tried several DVD's and one worked but other don't

Any ideas, everything else works fine.

Comment: which program are you using to play those DVDs

Comment: I've tried VLC and also dragon player. They both seem to react in a similar manner. Several years ago I used run the full Ubuntu and that I remember had more driver support so I thought maybe it was the more generic drivers in lubuntu that could be not using the full potential of the graphics card etc but I am no expert ....